# Add the total of a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd dataframe:

```
A B
1 2
2 3
3 2
```

I want: totalA = 1+2+3=6 and totalB = 2+3+2=7

I tried df.sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, your data is of type str.  Try:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum()

A    6
B    7
dtype: int64
```

---

What might happen is the the strings get concatenated to `123` and `232`.  But for whatever reason, Pandas casts those to `float` even when it started as string.

```
df.sum()

A    123.0
B    232.0
dtype: float64
```

---

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('123'), B=list('232'))
```